# React Native setState is not updating

Tags: react-native

I have a problem in updating state with `setState`, i.e. it's not updating state in my code:

```
const [term,setTerm] = useState('');
const [results,setResults] = useState([]);
 
const searchApi= async()=>{
  const response = await  yelp.get('',{
    params:{
      limit:10,
      query_term:term
    }
  });
  
  console.log("result before set:",results);
  setResults({response})
  console.log("result after set:",results);
  console.log("result",response);
}
```

I want to change the results state but it is not updating. In output it shows empty array.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `setResults(response)` instead of `setResults({response})`. `{}` is an object, not an array like in your initial value in `useState([])`.

Comment: this also not work setResults(response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating your state like this.

console log will not working because `React.setState` is Async task and it takes time to compelete.

```
setResults([...response])
```